# Transferring large files between an Ubuntu machine and a windows machine

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I have two computers, one with Ubuntu 14.04 (PC1), the other one with Windows-7 (PC2). I have a >2GB file to transfer from PC1 to PC2 and I got a timeout message by using the usual way, i.e. using the menu of gnome-classic (network, windows icon, etc). Therefore I did this in my home directory:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //PC2/PARTAGE/ Windows/ -o  username=USERNAME,rw,user,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

And that works ! The directory ${HOME}/Windows of PC1 is mounted on //PC2/PARTAGE (partage = share in English, it is the name of my shared folder)

**BUT** the transfer rate is about 14MBytes/s, instead of 50-70MBytes/s as usual (PC1 and PC2 are related to each other by a gigabit switch, I never reach 100MBytes/s probably because of the ethernet cables).

Why is this method slower ? It is my question. What is wrong in this method ?

Comment: is FTP a option?

Comment: For a quick transfer of files, I usually start a python web server: http://askubuntu.com/a/520612/. Quick and fast.

Comment: Indeed, your method works fine too. Transfer rate ~80-90MBytes/s. Thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue may be that you are mounting it as a filesystems etc, which is more complicated - using FTP (File Transfer Protocol) would be ideal for this, as it just transferring a file. To use it you first need to install a server *(probably easiest on the Ubuntu machine)*  - you can do that with:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

You then need to edit the security settings so not anyone can log in - you can do this by running `sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf`, and replacing `anonymous_enable=YES` with `anonymous_enable=NO`. You may also want to set the `write_enable` entry,  depending on whether you want to allow files to be created over FTP or not. You can then save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

You then need to restart vsftpd *(I think this is the right command...)*

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

You then need a FTP client (on the Windows machine) to access the FTP server - for Windows [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is good, but is hosted on Sourceforge, which now sadly has many ad fake download links, and now has adware installers for some of the more popular apps<sup>[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itbMqm.png)](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/11/08/gimp_dumps_sourceforge_over_dodgy_ads_and_installer/)[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itbMq.png)](http://blog.gluster.org/2013/08/how-far-the-once-mighty-sourceforge-has-fallen/)</sup> *(I don't think the version FileZilla_3.9.0.6_win32-setup.exe [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla_Client/3.9.0.6/) has this issue (though it did - looks fine under Wine anyway))* - basically don't use the installer if it looks like this:

[image]

You can then enter the IP address and login details of the Ubuntu machine, and transfer the files.

**NOTE:** Note if you want something potentially more secure you can use SFTP - this can be done by using a SSH server on the Linux machine (using the `openssh` packages), and `sftp` in Filezilla.

Comment: There is another ftp/sftp client : WinSCP (http://winscp.net/). By using the ftp server above and a ftp client on Windows-7, the transfer rate reaches the 100MBytes/s : so my ethernet cables are very good. I already had a ssh server on my linux machine. By using the sftp client feature of WinSCP, I have a transfer rate of about 15MBytes/s, like mounting the windows partition as a filesystem. So the reason here is the encryption I guess. To summarize, your method works. And no timeout anymore of course.

Comment: So the transfer rate between linux and windows is ~60MBytes/s by samba, ~100MBytes/s by ftp, ~15MBytes/s by mounting as a filesystem and by sftp.

Comment: There is safe version of filezilla at http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/filezilla_portable

Comment: @hlcs also https://ninite.com/ I think (currently...) I'm not sure but I think there are some safe download links from the Filezilla project page.

Comment: winscp is quite easy to use, I recommend that.  Also, instead of using IP, you can just use the machine name if on the local network

Answer (score -1):

Install sftp package on Ubuntu machine:

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install vsftpd**

Now it's working fine.